# Python Flask: How to pass a variable to multiple routes across multiple blueprints?

Tags: python, flask

I have a variable, `company` (a model instance), that I want to pass through all of the routes across multiple blueprints. I could query it at the top of each blueprint and expose to all routes inside each blueprint. But I'd like to expose the variable across multiple blueprints.

For example, if I had three blueprints (blueprint_1, blueprint_2, and blueprint_3), I could do something like the following.

In blueprint_1/routes.py

```
blueprint_1 = Blueprint("blueprint_1", __name__)
company = Company.query.first()

# expose company to routes below
...
```

In blueprint_2/routes.py

```
blueprint_2 = Blueprint("blueprint_2", __name__)
company = Company.query.first()

# expose company to routes below
...
```

In blueprint_3/routes.py

```
blueprint_2 = Blueprint("blueprint_2", __name__)
company = Company.query.first()

# expose company to routes below
...
```

To me, this look repetitive, especially if I have multiple variables that I want to pass across multiple blueprints. Is there a cleaner way to achieve the same effect? I'm using an app factory pattern so I tried to putting it under `create_app` function, but it did not work. Where can I define `company`, so I can expose it to all blueprints?

Comment: What do you mean "it did not work"?
You could try putting the variable in the app config. Then from each view you call `current_app().config['company']`